# TypeError: mediaRecorder is undefined when mediaRecorder.stop() is called

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webrtc

I am using the code from here [MediaStreamRecorder](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder) to record video and
audio in single webm format. I have modified the code as per my use case.

what i am trying to do here is whenever user clicks on a button like "**Start**" it should start recording a video and when they click on "**Stop**" it should stop. but Whenever I try to stop video ( using `mediaRecorder.stop()` ) it doesn't stops at all, it throws some error like

`TypeError: medaiRecorder is undefined`

and the recording continues even after calling Stop() on mediaRecorder

PS: I am using Rails.Also, the same code works well when using onclick().

Below is the log from console:

```
"start worked "
TypeError: mediaRecorder is undefined
"stop worked"
```

here is the code i am trying to run:

```
<div class="container">
<button id="first">Start!!</button>
<button id="second">Stop!!</button>

     </div>   
<script>

  var mediaConstraints = {
  audio: !!navigator.mozGetUserMedia,
  video: true
  };

var mediaRecorder;

function onMediaSuccess(stream) {
    var mediaRecorder = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.mimeType = 'video/webm';
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (blob) {
         // do something with blob
    };
    mediaRecorder.start(3000);
}

function onMediaError(e) {
    console.error('media error', e);
}

document.getElementById('first').addEventListener('click',firstHandler,false);
document.getElementById('second').addEventListener('click',secondHandler,false);

    function firstHandler() 
    {  
        console.log('start worked ');
        navigator.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints, onMediaSuccess, onMediaError);
    }

    function secondHandler() 
    {  
        console.log('stop worked');
        mediaRecorder.stop();
    }


// below function via: http://goo.gl/B3ae8c
  function bytesToSize(bytes) 
  {
    var k = 1000;
    var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
    if (bytes === 0) return '0 Bytes';
    var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k)),10);
    return (bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toPrecision(3) + ' ' + sizes[i];
  }

// below function via: http://goo.gl/6QNDcI
  function getTimeLength(milliseconds) 
  {
    var data = new Date(milliseconds);
    return data.getUTCHours()+" hours, "+data.getUTCMinutes()+" minutes and "+data.getUTCSeconds()+" second(s)";
  }

////////////////////////////////////////////
// Identify Browser with below code
///////////////////////////////////////////

// function GetBrowser()
// {
//     return  navigator ? navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() : "other";
// }
// console.log(GetBrowser());

</script>
```

Comment: `var mediaRecorder = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream);` is your problem, must be `mediaRecorder = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream);`

Comment: OK that was something terrible , thanks that solved the issue :)